# Why appengine taksqueues are forced into a lowering processing rate?

Tags: google-app-engine, task-queue

While executing tasks I see the following in the admin console in the 'Task queues' section. This is a paid app and am prepared to use more resources and pay for them. Any clue what might be causing it:

"To conserve system resources during peak usage, App Engine is enforcing a processing rate lower than the maximum rate for this queue"

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app is not scaling properly.

Hover your mouse over the question mark at the top-right of the console screen.  You will most likely see a tooltip message like:

"App Engine is enforcing a processing rate lower than the maximum rate for this queue either because your application is returning HTTP 503 codes or because currently there is no instance available to execute a request."

So, check your logs for 503's.  Check your resource settings to make sure your app can properly handle the traffic.

Comment: Indeed I have one service/module pinned down to only one instances and some tasks in that queue were accidentally serviced by that instance.

Comment: btw, It look like some tasks are just lost while getting this message, is it expected behaviour?

Comment: I had the same issue. The task is showing  some warning and task are getting skipped. No trace at all either on the log.